# Is there any way to support geolocation in DocRaptor pdf generation?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, geolocation, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Working on pdf generation i have used phantomjs for same and it supports Geolocation because PhantomJS is built on the WebKit browser. I want to try DocRaptor for pdf generation which uses PrinceXML, an engine designed specifically for creating PDFs, but it not supports geolocation.

The HTML for print is having script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

it gives error like:
[Javascript Error] Geolocation is not supported by this browser.

Is there any way to support geolocation in DocRaptor pdf generation?

Comment: I'm a developer for DocRaptor. That is not something we natively support, but perhaps we can find a workaround. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the geolocation?

Comment: As a followup to my previous comment, it may work if you run it through our custom (non-PrinceXML) javascript engine: https://docraptor.com/documentation#api_javascript.

Comment: @jamespaden thanks for reply, I have tried same option javascript: true but still its not working.